# Moving the average bar in a bar chart from beginning of series to the end

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a chart that is receiving its data from a table. At the end of the column in question there is the average. I have the column as one data series and the the average at the bottom as another data series.

[image: Columns]

I need to move the average bar from the beginning of the chart to the end.

[image: Chart]
[image: Series1]
[image: Series2]

I have looked all over the net an cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: Since the date range changes all the time I added VBA code to put Average at the end of the date range then I added a column with the average in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organize your data on another sheet so it looks like this:

```
+---+----------+------+---------+
|   |    A     |  B   |    C    |
+---+----------+------+---------+
| 1 |          | Data | Average |
| 2 | 1/1/2014 | 40   |         |
| 3 | 2/1/2014 | 30   |         |
| 4 | 3/1/2014 | 25   |         |
| 5 | Average  |      | 31.67   |
+---+----------+------+---------+
```

Then select `A1` through the bottom right corner, and insert a column chart.

The trick here is each series needs to have the same number of data points, but each point only has a value in one series or the other.

Edit: Set the "Series Overlap" of each series to 100% to center the bars on the axis labels.